# using "foreach" for running different classifiers in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I am trying to use foreach to run different classifiers on my data, but it doesn't work. In fact it doesn't return me anything.
my purpose is to parallelize my process. here is the simplified of my code:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl<-makeCluster(no_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)
registerDoParallel(no_cores)

model_list<-foreach(i = 1:2, 
              .combine = c,.packages=c("e1071","randomeForest"))  %dopar%  
  if (i==1){
    model1<-svm(x = X,y = as.factor(Y),type = "C-classification",probability = T)
  }
  if (i==2){
    mode2<-randomForest(x = X,y = as.factor(Y), ntree=100, norm.votes=FALSE,importance = T)
}
```

My way of parallelizing is correct overall?
Thanks indeed.

Comment: I'm also a beginner, but why you register no_cores? Use cbind/rbind instead c. You have to recall, return your result variables model1/2.

Comment: @Jimbou, thanks. yes i need to use `rbind` instead of `c` and I mistakenly registered cores two times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you're not enclosing the body of the foreach loop in curly braces. Because `%dopar%` is a binary operator, you have to be careful about precedence, which is why I recommend always using curly braces.

Also, you shouldn't use `c` as the combine function. Since `svm` and `randomForest` return objects, the default behavior of returning the results in a list is appropriate. Combining them with `c` will give you a garbage result.

Finally, it doesn't make sense to call `registerDoParallel` twice. It doesn't hurt, but it makes your code confusing.

I suggest:

```
library(doParallel)
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
registerDoParallel(no_cores)

model_list <- foreach(i = 1:2,
              .packages=c("e1071","randomForest"))  %dopar% {
  if (i==1) {
    svm(x = X,y = as.factor(Y),type = "C-classification",
       probability = T)
  } else {
    randomForest(x = X,y = as.factor(Y), ntree=100, norm.votes=FALSE,
                 importance = T)
  }
}
```

I also removed the two unnecessary variable assignments to `model1` and `model2`. Those variables won't be defined correctly on the master, and it obscures how the foreach loop really works.

Comment: thanks, It is really helpful. overall, my code for parallelization of two classifier, which are not run parallel, is correct?

Comment: I still can not predict which each model. this one returns nothing `pred<-predict(model_list[1], testdata)`. where is the problem?

Comment: @Cina `model_list[1]` is a list containing a model object. Try using `model_list[[1]]` instead.